# nth-of-type not working inside a list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I cant seem to change the background of my divs when they are inside an li. I think the issue is to do with the order in which my elements are in.

```
<ul class="featured-items">
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
</ul>

.featured-items li .inner:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-image: url(../images/phone.jpg);
}

.featured-items li .inner:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: url(../images/firelace.jpg);
}
```

At the moment, every inner shows `"phone.jpg"`.

Comment: I think `:nth-of-type` should be with `li` like `.featured-items li:nth-of-type(1) .inner { ... }`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type _“The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree”_ – your `.inner` elements don’t have _any_ siblings, they are each the only child of their parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like `.featured-items li:nth-of-type(2)>div.inner`

```css
.featured-items li:nth-of-type(1)>div.inner  {
    background-color: red;
}

.featured-items li:nth-of-type(2)>div.inner {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="featured-items">
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div>v</div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div>f</div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div>vl</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to select the `.inner` by `:nth-of-type()`, but rather the `li`. That is: "select the (n)th list element and apply the following styles to its `.inner` child.

```css
.featured-items li:nth-of-type(1) .inner {
    background-image: url(../images/phone.jpg);
}

.featured-items li:nth-of-type(2) .inner {
    background-image: url(../images/firelace.jpg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="featured-items">
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
        <li><div class="inner"><div class="item-content"></div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```css
li {
 border:1px solid red;
}
.featured-items li:nth-of-type(1) > .inner{
    background-image:url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/flower-clip-art-4c9arqMcE.png);
    background-size:20px 20px;
}

.featured-items li:nth-of-type(2) > .inner {
    background-image:url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/E/X/A/4/f/pink-daisy-md.png);
  background-size:20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="featured-items">
   <li>
      <div class="inner"><div class="item-content">1</div></div>
  </li>
 <li>
      <div class="inner"><div class="item-content">2</div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inner"><div class="item-content">3</div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```